# Gridsearch CV give different best parameters when trained in different data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv, mlp

I am looking for the best way to tune a Randomforest Classifier and MLP Classifier in sklearn. The problem is that the Grisearch CV gives me slightly different best parameters each time I run my code. I assume that this happens because each time my train and test data are splitted differently. I have 2 questions:

1) Giving me a bit different best parameters each time means that my data are noisy or something like that?

2) Is there any way to choose the best parameters that fit all my training sets? At least the most usual best parameters.

Bonus Question: I want to classify 3 variables. My general classification accuracy_score(y_test1,pred1) gives arround 57% which i assume that is low. I mostly care of the high probability classifications. When I calculate predict_proba(X_test1)>0.8 and count the correct and false classifications I get a score 0.90% which is satisfactory. Should I be satisfied with this process? When I run on new test data, will my model's high probability predictions achieve the 0.90% score?

Best regards,
Nick

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions, rather separate these into distinct postings.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a seed to maintain reproducibility of results. Try using the `train_test_split` function in SKLearn to split your data and specify a value for the `random_seed` parameter. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). Having different distributions of the training data and testing data on separate runs and receiving different results does not mean there is noise in the signal.

2) Can you elaborate here? The `best_estimator_` and `best_params_` attributes of the `GridSearchCV` object, once it has been fit, should contain the data you need.